# killing app when Developer option (Don't keep activities) is set

Tags: android

I have two activities `A1` and `A2`, `A1` has Next button, Kill app button. `A2` has Kill app button.

`A1` (Next button) goes to `A2`. In Exit app of both activities I call `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` to kill the app completely. Now my problem is when Developer options(Don't keep activities) is enabled, and user is in `A1` then to `A2` and kill. App is directly going to `A1`, I know that if we enable the option android removes the activity that goes to back. But when I exit the app, why the android is treating as back key press. 
I have a big concern with this, because when I press HOME button, we just kill the app. When user re-enters the app android is directly to screen where have pressed HOME key. Can anyone tell what should I do to clear the backstack information completely for an app on Exit.

Comment: `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`  Why?  Why are you even trying to do this?  You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist and in the process, creating new ones.

Comment: Killing the App doesn't kill the history .. I dont think

Comment: Why do you care if the dev options are selected to begin with?

Comment: As this is high security related app, so wanted to kill the app if we user wants to exit the app. But I dont understand why android os is remembering the closed activities even though the app is cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

After calling activity A2, call finish(), like this:

```
callingActivityA2() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, activityA2.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
 }
```